# How do I get this cover page on Latex?

Tags: titles

I have designed the cover page as shown in the picture below, now I want it on latex (.tex) file. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Including the use of (what looks like) Comic Sans?

Comment: Please show the LaTeX you have tried; an MWE (from `\documentclass... to `\end{document}`)  will be of help. We have no idea what class you are thinking of using and any answer will depend on your desired class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The vertical rules are set using `\rule[<raise>]{<width>}{<height>}` with a negative `<raise>` lowering it below the baseline. The first and third rules are `6cm` tall while the middle one is `8cm` tall.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\setcounter{page}{0}

\mbox{}

\vfill

\begin{center}
  \large Notes on
  
  \LARGE\bfseries Algorithmic Complexity

  \bigskip\bigskip

  \rule[-3cm]{.4pt}{6cm}\quad
  \rule[-4cm]{.4pt}{8cm}\quad
  \rule[-3cm]{.4pt}{6cm}
  
  \bigskip\bigskip
  
  \large\mdseries Central Department of MscCSIT,
  
  Tu, Kirtipur
\end{center}

\vfill

\mbox{}

\clearpage

\pagestyle{plain}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: @Werner Thanks for the answer, really appreciated your help.

Comment: @BomjonBedu If you agree with the great `Werner` suggestion, then please accept the answer by clicking the `tick mark`...

Answer (score 3):

A TikZ solution:

[image: cover page]

I also show the algorithm:

[image: algorithm]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}

\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [yshift=6cm] at (current page.center) (t1) {\Large Notes On};
\node [yshift=5.3cm] at (current page.center) (t2) {\Large\bfseries Algorithmic Complexity};
\node [yshift=-6cm] at (current page.center) (b1) {\Large Tu, Kirtipur};
\node [yshift=-5.3cm] at (current page.center) (b2) {\Large Central Department of MscCSIT};

\node [yshift=4cm] at (current page.center) (a) {A};
\node [yshift=-4cm] at (current page.center) (b) {B};
\node [yshift=2cm,xshift=1.5cm] at (current page.center) (c) {C};
\node [yshift=-2cm,xshift=1.5cm] at (current page.center) (d) {D};
\node [yshift=2cm,xshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.center) (e) {E};
\node [yshift=-2cm,xshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.center) (f) {F};
\draw (a) edge (b);
\draw (c) edge (d);
\draw (e) edge (f);
\end{tikzpicture}


\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (current page.center) circle (6cm);
\draw (current page.center) circle (5.3cm);
\draw (current page.center) circle (4cm);
\draw  (current page.center)[xshift=1.5cm] circle (2cm);
\draw  (current page.center)[xshift=-1.5cm] circle  (2cm);
\node [yshift=6cm] at (current page.center) (t1) {\Large Notes On};
\node [yshift=5.3cm] at (current page.center) (t2) {\Large\bfseries Algorithmic Complexity};
\node [yshift=-6cm] at (current page.center) (b1) {\Large Tu, Kirtipur};
\node [yshift=-5.3cm] at (current page.center) (b2) {\Large Central Department of MscCSIT};

\node [yshift=4cm] at (current page.center) (a) {A};
\node [yshift=-4cm] at (current page.center) (b) {B};
\node [yshift=2cm,xshift=1.5cm] at (current page.center) (c) {C};
\node [yshift=-2cm,xshift=1.5cm] at (current page.center) (d) {D};
\node [yshift=2cm,xshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.center) (e) {E};
\node [yshift=-2cm,xshift=-1.5cm] at (current page.center) (f) {F};
\draw (a) edge (b);
\draw (c) edge (d);
\draw (e) edge (f);

\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (t1) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (t2) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (b1) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (b2) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (a) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (b) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (c) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (d) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (e) circle (0.1cm);
\draw [fill=red,opacity=0.4] (f) circle (0.1cm);
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```